# generate Arabic PDF report using Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

> I'm working in project that depend on generate reports using codeigniter.
>   I tried to use some libraries like mpdf and r&os it look like it work in English data but in arabic it doesn't work please Help and sorry for language

Comment: what error are you getting for arabic pdf

Comment: data return as ????? unknown characters and it takes along time for fetch more than 50 record